# how do you save the state of a datatable so that you don't have to filter the data again?

Tags: jquery, datatable

So I have a problem with my code, I'm trying to make it so that if I go to another page and go back to the index page, the Datatable will return to its previous state. Note that I have a filter button modal, so for example I want to go to another page, and then go back to the index page, I don't want to fill in the modal and filter all over again.

Here's what my table looks like:

```
<div id="kt_app_content" class="app-content flex-column-fluid">
                    <div id="kt_app_content_container" class="app-container container-xxl">
                        <div class="card card-flush">
                            <div class="card-header align-items-center py-5 gap-2 gap-md-5">
                                <div class="card-toolbar">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid w-250px ps-14" placeholder="Search Barang" id="searchBarang" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-toolbar flex-row-fluid justify-content-end gap-5">
                                    <button 
                                        type="button" 
                                        class="btn btn-primary mr-3" 
                                        data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                                        data-bs-target="#barangFilter">
                                        <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-6 svg-icon-muted me-1">
                                            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path d="M19.0759 3H4.72777C3.95892 3 3.47768 3.83148 3.86067 4.49814L8.56967 12.6949C9.17923 13.7559 9.5 14.9582 9.5 16.1819V19.5072C9.5 20.2189 10.2223 20.7028 10.8805 20.432L13.8805 19.1977C14.2553 19.0435 14.5 18.6783 14.5 18.273V13.8372C14.5 12.8089 14.8171 11.8056 15.408 10.964L19.8943 4.57465C20.3596 3.912 19.8856 3 19.0759 3Z" fill="currentColor" />
                                            </svg>
                                        </span>
                                        Filter
                                    </button>
                                    <div id="customButtonTemplate"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body pt-0">
                                <div class="table-both-scroll">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover order-column table-row-dashed fs-6 gy-5 nowrap" id="barangTable">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="text-center align-middle">No</td>
                                                <td class="text-center align-middle" width='15%'>Aksi</td>
                                                <td class="text-center align-middle">ID Barang</td>
                                                <td class="text-center align-middle">Kode Barang</td>
                                                <td class="text-center align-middle">Barang</td>
                                                <td class="text-center align-middle">Jenis Barang</td>
                                                <td class="text-center align-middle">Kategori Barang</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody></tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here's the filter modal:

```
<form class="modal fade" id="barangFilter" aria-labelledby="filterModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Filter</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group mb-3">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Data Klinik</label>
                            <select class="form-control remoteDataKlinik" name="dataKlinik"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonFilter">Filter</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the script:

```
<script>
    var baseUrl = "<?= base_url();?>";
    function initRemoteDataKlinik(object) {
        var object = $(object);
        object.select2({
            dropdownParent: $("#barangFilter"),
            ajax: {
                url: `${baseUrl}/RemoteData/remoteDataKlinik`,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: function (param) {
                    var query = { search: param.term }; // term merupakan hasil default dari search
                    return query;
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.NAMA,
                                id: item.UUID,
                            };
                        }),
                    };
                },
            },
            cache: true,
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            language: {
                inputTooShort: function () {
                return "Minimal 3 karakter atau lebih";
                },
            },
            placeholder: "Cari Data Klinik",
            width: "100%",
            allowClear: true,
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#barangFilter').modal('show');
        initRemoteDataKlinik('.remoteDataKlinik');
        var idDataKlinik = $('.remoteDataKlinik').val();
        generateDatatables(idDataKlinik);

        function generateDatatables(idDataKlinik){

            var table = $('#barangTable').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "language": {
                    "emptyTable": "Tolong pilih Data Klinik terlebih dahulu!"
                },
                "ajax": {
                    url: `${baseUrl}/Barang/Barang/barangDatatables`,
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{
                        idDataKlinik: idDataKlinik,
                    },
                },
                "aLengthMenu": [
                    [25, 50, 100, -1],
                    [25, 50, 100, "All"]
                ],
            });
            
            new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
                lengthChange: false,
                buttons: ['print', 'pdf', 'excel', 'csv']
            });
            table.buttons().container().appendTo('#customButtonTemplate');

            $("#searchBarang").keyup(function() {
                var table = $('#barangTable').DataTable();
                table.search(this.value).draw();
            });

            $('#buttonFilter').click(function() {
                if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#barangTable')){
                    $('#barangTable').DataTable().clear().destroy();
                    generateDatatables($('.remoteDataKlinik').val());
                    $('#barangFilter').modal('hide');
                    $('#searchBarang').val('');
                    table.search('').draw();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have tried using `"stateSave": true` but it doesn't seem to work as the Datatable didn't save its previous state. I'm still fairly new to JS and JQuery in general but never touched on this problem before, this is my first time having to implement this kind of feature into my assignment so some help would be very appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technically possible, it's up to you to decide how this functions in your specific environment and requirements.
That said, one possibility is to use the browser local storage to save the filtering state of the DataTables.

Steps:

1. When the table is filtered, save the filtering state to the browser
   local storage.
2. When the page is loaded, check if there is a saved
   filtering state in the local storage.
3. If so, apply the filtering to
   the table. When the user navigates away from the page, save the
   filtering state to the local storage.
4. When the user comes back to the page, check if there is a saved filtering state in the local storage. If so, apply the filtering to the table.

Adjust for your needs:

```js
// Save the filtering state to local storage when the table is filtered
$('#myTable').on('search.dt', function() {
  localStorage.setItem('myTable_filter', $('#myTable_filter input').val());
});

// Apply the saved filtering state when the page is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
  var filterValue = localStorage.getItem('myTable_filter');
  if (filterValue) {
    $('#myTable_filter input').val(filterValue).keyup();
  }
});

// Save the filtering state to local storage when the user navigates away from the page
$(window).on('unload', function() {
  localStorage.setItem('myTable_filter', $('#myTable_filter input').val());
});

// Apply the saved filtering state when the user comes back to the page
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var filterValue = localStorage.getItem('myTable_filter');
  if (filterValue) {
    $('#myTable_filter input').val(filterValue).keyup();
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, it wasn't what I was looking for, but it gave me a pretty good idea and now its working, thanks for the answer